# asp.net mvc 4 javascript inside razor block throws error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my razor code which throws error:

```
@section script
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            @if (TempData["Message"] != null)
            {
                showNotification("'" + TempData["Message"].ToString() + "'");
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

It says `showNotification` doesn't exist. It thinks this is a C# code where it's a javascript function. Could anybody please let me know how do I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: I know this isn't the answer, and that people will show you one of the many ways to fix this (@: syntax for one). I'd just remove the @if statement completely, and not call ToString() explicitly but let it be called implicitly. That'd work

Comment: The problem with TempData is that if the TempData["Foo"] is null, then u get a NPE. so use ViewBag

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Throw a `text` tag around it, since the compiler thinks your JavaScript is Razor syntax.  When you do this, you will need to add a `@` to the TempData call.

```
@section script
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            @if (TempData["Message"] != null)
            {
                <text>showNotification('@TempData["Message"].ToString()');</text>
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Martin's answer, you can also put @: in front of the showNotification call.  The @: syntax tells Razor to treat that single line as HTML, where the  tells Razor to treat anything within the text tag as HTML (useful for multi line, where @: is good for single line).